# iCalendar how to block time for multiple calendars

Tags: ical, google-calendar

I have multiple Gmail accounts and when I have a meeting in the calendar let's say as an example `A`, I would like to create a `busy` event in all the other calendars.

Any idea if this is possible using iCalendar or maybe another app?